# H2O Flow: How does H2O flow UI treat data types differently

Tags: machine-learning, h2o

Specifically, what is the difference in how `H2O` treats `enum` and `string` data types in contrast to '`int's` and '`numerical`' types?

For example, say I have a binary classifier that takes input samples that have features

```
x1=(1 of 10 possible favorite ice cream flavors (enum))

x2=(some random phrase (string))

x3=(some number (int))
```

What would be the difference in how the classifier treats these types during training?

When uploading data into `h2o` Flow `UI`, I get the option to convert certain data types (like `enum`) to 'numerical.' This makes me think that there is more than just string-to-number mapping going on when I just leave the '`enum`' as an '`enum`' (not converting to '`numerical`' type), but I can't find information on what that difference is.

Clarification would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "enum" type is the type of encoding you'll want to use for categorical features.  If the categorical features are encoded as "enum", then the tree-based algorithms like Random Forest and GBM will be able to handle these features in a smart way.  Most other implementations of RFs and GBM force you to do a one-hot expansion of the categorical features (into K dummy columns), but in H2O, the tree-based methods can use these features without any expansion.  The exact whay that the variables are handled can be controlled using the [`categorical_encoding`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/categorical_encoding.html) argument.

If you have an ordered categorical variable, then it might be okay to encode that as "int", however, the effect of doing that on model performance will depend on the data.

If you were to convert an "enum" column to "numeric" that would simply encode each category as an integer and you'd lose the notion that those numbers represent categories (so it's not recommended).

You should not use the "string" type in H2O unless you are going to exclude that column from the set of predictors.  It would make sense to use a "string" column for text, but you'll probably want to parse (e.g. tokenize) that text to generate new numeric or enum features that will be included in the set of predictors.